# Play media while downloading

Tags: ios, stream, nsurlconnection, media

I use an `NSURLConnection` to get a media file downloaded. While downloading I store the content at a NEMutableData and write it down to a cache file. 
Now I want to play this file while downloading with `AVPlayer` (Not AVAudioPlayer) because it could be video.

At the time the `AVPlayer` get the URL to the cache file it looks like the player copy the state of the file because the player don't get any changes and after a few seconds it holds because of the end of data.

Does anybody has a better solution but to download everything first until start playing, or is there a way to give the AVPlayer an Internet `NSURL` and preload the rest while streaming?

Comment: have you got any solution. I'm looking for this

Comment: My current solution is paralell to start the download and the audio stream. On completion i switch playback to the local file